# Do I need to initialize Crashlytics if I need to log non-fatal exception?

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

Before I called the method

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(new Exception("..."))
```

Do I need to initialize Crashlytics like this

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

though I've initialized in the main screen?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to as long as you have it initialized in the main screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize Crashlytics on your application class on the onCreate() method. That way all the fatal exceptions are caught by default and when creating a log you only need to call the

```
Crashlytics.getInstance()
```

every time you need it